# How to split first 4 rows and sum the remaining records and show as last record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below

```
col1    col2    col3
i1        23      36
i2        48      21
i3        28       4
i4       349      12
…       
…       
i200     287      32
```

Now, how to get the result as below

```
col1    col2              col3
i1        23                36
i2        48                21
i3        28                 4
i4       349                12
>i4      (sum of            (sum of remaining)
         col2 remaining)
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
select col1,col2,col3 from dbo.t3 where col1<='i4'
union
select '>i4',SUM(col2),SUM(col3) from dbo.t3 where col1>'i4'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by a calculated field, like this:

```
WITH cte (col1, col2, col3) AS (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN col1 IN ('i1','i2','i3','i4') THEN col1
            ELSE '>i4'
        END AS col1
    ,   col2
    ,   col3
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT col1, SUM(col2) AS col2, SUM(col3) AS col3
FROM cte
GROUP BY col1
```

The above query uses the [*Common Table Expression (CTE)*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) feature to avoid specifying the same expression multiple times.

Comment: +1, you could have tweeked it by writing: when col1 in('i1','i2','i3','i4') then col1 else '>i4'

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Thanks - great suggestion, I like it very much.